# VARIABLE DE CLASE variable de instancia python SETEO DE VALOR

Tags: python, variables

Ok,  Reescribo la consulta viendo lo que me han respondido.
LA DUDA:  Tengo varias clases y no s'e como definir una:

- VARIABLE DE INSTANCIA,
- UNA VARIABLE DE CLASE
- COMO HACER EL SETEO DE LA VARIABLE DE CLASE.

Main.py

```
from Departamento import Departamento

listaDep = []  
listaEmp = []

class Main:

    def cargarEmpleado():
        numId = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO ID DEL EMPLEADO. \n'))
        while(numId != 0 ):
            nombre = input('INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO. \n')
            apelli = input('INGRESE EL APELLIDO DEL EMPLEADO. \n')
            sueldo = float(input('INGRESE EL SUELDO\n'))
            objetoEmpleado = [numId, nombre, apelli, sueldo]
            listaEmp.append(objetoEmpleado)
            numId = int(input('PROXIMO NUMERO DE EMPLEADO. \n'))

    def listarEmpleados():
        print('LISTA: ', listaEmp)

    while True:
        print ('*********MENU*********** \n')
        print ('1_ CARGA     UN     EMPLEADO   AL        SISTEMA.')
        print ('2_ MUESTRA LOS EMPLEADOS CARGADOS EN EL  SISTEMA.')
        print ('0_ SALE DEL PROGRAMA. \n')
        opcion = int(input('INGRESE UNA OPCION: '))    

        if opcion == 1:
            cargarEmpleado()
    
        elif opcion == 2:
            listarEmpleados()
    
        elif opcion == 0:
            exit()
```

Departamento.py
Aca, definino presupuesto_maximo = 0.00001 pero se que hay una forma de definir esta var de clase de forma tal que tome un valor inicial sin que yo fije uno y sea modificado.
Tambi'en, aca van a ver que tengo que una llamada desde el main? es asi?
Lo que planteaba, no s'e como se maneja la llamada al metodo que hace el set del primer valor.

```
from Empleado import Empleado

class Departamento:

    presupuesto_maximo = 0.00001  # Variable De Clase.

    def __init__(self, numOficina, nombreOficina, cantEmpleados, listaEmpleado, presupuesto):
        '''Definicion de Departamento.'''
        self.numOficina = numOficina
        self.cantEmpleados = cantEmpleados
        self.nombreOficina = nombreOficina
        self.listaEmpleado = []
        self.presupuesto_actual = presupuesto
        self.registrar_Presupuesto(presupuesto)

    def registrar_Presupuesto(self, nuevo_Presupuesto):
        self.presupuesto_actual = nuevo_Presupuesto
        if self.presupuesto_actual > self.presupuesto_maximo:
            self.__class__.presupuesto_maximo = 
self.presupuesto_actual
```

Empleado.py

```
class Empleado:
    def __init__(self, id, nombre, apellido, sueldo):
        '''Definicion de un empleado.'''
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.sueldo = sueldo
```

Espero haber cumplido con todo lo necesario para que puedan ayudarme.
Si falta algo, estoy atento.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: @Alfabravo.  Ahi subi la pregunta corregida con lo qu eespero les sirva para que puedan responderme.  Quedo atento a cualquier otra consulta por si surge y mas atento aun a la respuesta.  Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo, cual es la pregunta? Ya has declarado la variable de clase y las de instancia

Comment: @Christian.  Esta escrito en tres lineas.

Comment: @AleBuo.  No entiendo lo que dices.  Lo que escrib'i, no s'e si es correcto. Por favor,  Podr'ias ser m'as claro.?

Answer (score 0):

Planteamos un ejemplo simple: la clase `Figura` contiene una lista de vértices que definen una figura geométrica. Para definir un objeto, empleamos varias figuras.

Para desplegar el total de figuras en pantalla necesitamos aplicar un factor de zoom a todas ellas, para que todas crezcan o disminuyan en la misma medida. Esta es la definición:

```
class Figura:
    zoom = 1
    def __init__(self, lista_vertices):
        self.vertices = lista_vertices
```

Aquí `zoom` es una variable de clase, compartida por todos los objetos `Figura`.

`vertices` es una variable de instancia; es particular a un objeto `Figura`.

Para ilustrar la diferencia, agreguemos a la clase un método `__str__` que retorne sus vértices ajustados por el zoom:

```
def __str__(self):
    ajustados = []
    for vertice in self.vertices:
        nuevo_vertice = (vertice[0] * self.zoom), (vertice[1] * self.zoom)
        ajustados.append(nuevo_vertice)
    return str(ajustados)
```

Este método recorre la lista de vértices original, no alterados, del objeto y aplica a cada coordenada (x, y) un ajuste por el zoom, produciendo un nuevo para (x * zoom, y * zoom).

Una variable de clase normalmente se accesa usando `nombre_de_clase.nombre_variable`. En este ejemplo sería `Figura.zoom`. Dentro de un método de la clase, igual puedes usar `self.zoom`.

Producida la lista de vértices ajustados, se genera su representación como cadena y se devuelve.

#### Demo

En este ejemplo definimos dos rectangulos y vemos como cambiar el zoom afecta a ambos.

```
class Figura:
    zoom = 1
    def __init__(self, lista_vertices):
        self.vertices = lista_vertices

    def __str__(self):
        ajustados = []
        for vertice in self.vertices:
            nuevo_vertice = (vertice[0] * self.zoom), (vertice[1] * self.zoom)
            ajustados.append(nuevo_vertice)
        return str(ajustados)

rectangulo = Figura([(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1, 0)])
print(f"Zoom = {Figura.zoom} {rectangulo}") # Zoom = 1 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]


Figura.zoom = 2
print(f"Zoom = {Figura.zoom} {rectangulo}") # Zoom = 2 [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0)]


rectangulo2 = Figura([(3,2), (1,1), (4,2), (4, 6)])
print(f"Zoom = {Figura.zoom} {rectangulo2}") # Zoom = 2 [(6, 4), (2, 2), (8, 4), (8, 12)]


Figura.zoom = 4
print(f"Zoom = {Figura.zoom} {rectangulo}") # Zoom = 4 [(0, 0), (0, 4), (4, 4), (4, 0)]

print(f"Zoom = {Figura.zoom} {rectangulo2}") # Zoom = 4 [(12, 8), (4, 4), (16, 8), (16, 24)]
```

Comment: Tal vez, no fui claro.  El problema es: VARIABLE DE INSTANCIA,
UNA VARIABLE DE CLASE , COMO HACER EL SETEO DE LA VARIABLE DE CLASE.  Con 3 tres clases.  Encuentro por todos lados estos ejemplos que no me aclaran lo que necesito.  Espero haber sido claro.  saludos. @CandidMoe

Comment: @MauricioLuisVega por lo que se entiende en tu pregunta lo que necesitas es lo que dice CandidMoe en su respuesta y es lo mismo que yo hubiera publicado. Tal vez tu pregunta no es muy clara :/

Comment: @Christian.  Sigo estudiando.  Que sigan todos bien.

Comment: listo, resuelto.  gracias por la rta. hasta el proximo problema.